# What to use as ID and PK

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a small question. I want so save information about a product in a sql database. That product has a unique 12 part number.

The product is going to be linked several times in the database. What should I use as unique id? The part number? or should I use the auto incremented id value?

What is better performance wise, and what is better in general?

Comment: I recommend having a unique auto-incremented id for almost every table and using this for foreign key relationships.

Comment: Having an "artificial" ID makes it easier if you have a case where you nee to correct the part number of an existing product. On the other hand you need another unique constraint/index for the part number.

Comment: Use of surrogate key (auto-incremented id) will be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a "meaningless" surrogate key (an auto-increment, a globally unique ID, etc.) on your table, even though you do have a unique identifier that has meaning in the real world (your 12-digit part number).

The main reason for this is that anything that has meaning in the real world is subject to change: part numbers change when companies merge, registration numbers change on renewal, etc. On top of that, there is always a possibility of mis-typing the number, and having to correct it later.

It is very easy to change an attribute that is not your primary key when this happens: it is a simple update of an attribute. Changing a primary key becomes very hard, though, because you may have foreign keys referencing it from other tables. This reason alone is sufficient to decide in favor of surrogate keys on your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use automatically generated BigInteger/Integer (depending on your needs) column as `PRIMARY KEY` and store part number as `UNIQUE` (this would be a candidate key). You would benefit from space that is required to store this in tables that are part of relations and more values would probably fit within a single page. If, by any chance, you'd need to change product number, this scenario would be beneficial to do so.

You would, though, need an additional `JOIN` even if you only need the part number from a table which holds foreign key relationship to your product table. More often than not if you want to display part number you also want some additional information from product table itself, so that doesn't hurt so much (since databases are optimized in a way to quickly perform join operations).

Be sure to create an index on column which is a `FOREIGN KEY` so in this case something like `id_product` in all tables which hold the relation to speed up matching operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice is between a natural and surrogate primary key. There are a [bunch of trade-offs](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-for-choosing-between-a-surrogate-and-natural-primary-key/) here.

The good news is that performance is unlikely to be one of them - as long as you can search using an index, a natural and surrogate key are likely to perform the same.

The data you store may have a unique attribute - SKU, social security number, etc. - and it may seem logical to use this when creating your schema. However, this opens you up to a whole range of edge cases.

- What if the user enters the data incorrectly and wants to change it? Changing primary and foreign keys is a terrible idea.
- What if the system that generates your natural keys has a bug and generates duplicates?
- What if the system that generates your natural keys is retired and you get records with incompatible data formats? Re-building your schema to move from integers to strings for your primary/foreign keys is horrible.
- What if you want to integrate with multiple systems generating data, and they disagree about data formats?

I've seen all these "what-ifs" happen.

I'd go for a surrogate key, using an auto-increment or GUID.